# How to export source layer intersections in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, intersection, dxf

I have source layer with areas (polygons) and intersect (second) layer with simple polyline structure. When I set up intersection, I got 6 objects in the results, its ok. After that I need to export to DXF or MIF only that parts (areas) of source layer, that intersects with intersect (second) layer.

So, how can I do that? If I select just my newly created intersection layer and export it to DXF - it just displays a second (intersect layer), not a intersect parts of source layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the *intersection* tool, you could try doing the following:

---

1. Use the **Select by location** tool from the menubar:

   ```
   Vector > Research Tools > Select by location
   ```

   or

   ```
   Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector selection tools > Select by location
   ```

---

2. Select the polygon layer as the *Layer to select from* and your line layer as the *Additional layer*. Then choose the `intersects` predicate as shown in the image:

   [image: Select by location]

   Run the tool.

---

3. The polygons which intersect the lines should be selected. Now you can *right-click* the polygon layer, choose `Save As...` set the output format and make sure you check the `Save only selected features` option:

   [image: Save selected features]

   The output should hopefully contain the polygons which intersect the lines in your specified format.

Comment: @geosys - Most welcome, glad it worked :)